# Change in an item of a LongListSelector's ItemsSource doesn't appear

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I have a page with a LongListSelector in my app. I also have a ObservableCollection that contains items of streamItem, a custom class that mainly holds some strings. Upon page load, I set the LongListSelector's ItemsSource to the ObservableCollection. The LongListSelector will now show the streamItems as expected, with the data bindings working properly.

However, now I'd like to update a streamItem. For example, I want to change a string in one of those items. I would expect this change, thanks to the data binding, to immediately be reflected in the LongListSelector, but it doesn't happen.

What can I do to make the LongListSelector update as soon as I change something in its ItemsSource? Here's a condensed set of code I'm using.

The streamItem Class:

```
Public Class streamItem
    Public Property headerText As String
    Public Property msgText As String
End Class
```

Decleration of the variable tableData, which is the ObservableCollection:

```
Public Shared tableData As New ObservableCollection(Of streamItem)
```

Upon page load, add an item to tableData and set the LongListSelector's (its name is tblStream) ItemsSource:

```
Dim newItem As New App.streamItem
newItem.headerText ="Header"
newItem.msgText = "Some other text"
App.tableData.Add(newItem)

tblStream.ItemsSource = App.tableData
```

The XAML part:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="tblStream">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding headerText}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding msgText}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

To test, I created a button that does this:

```
App.tableData.Item(0).msgText = "Text changed."
```

When clicked, I expected the LongListSelector to reflect this change, but nothing happens. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` notifies the View when items are inserted/deleted/moved. If you want to see changes in the properties of items that are already in the collection, then the item class - in your case, `streamItem`, should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and fire this event when you set the property.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need, thanks! It's so easy when you know what you're looking for. :) Now that I know I need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, I found a vb.net example on MSDN which proved very useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx